# Rails 2.3 custom validation with loop to check existance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, associations

I have a model called Booking, on create this should check if an association is found.
The code is:

```
  def price_details
    variant.tour.price_details.each do |pd|
      if category == pd.category
        if date_from >= pd.from_date && date_from <= pd.to_date
          return true
        else
          errors.add_to_base('error message')
          return false
        end
      end
    end
    nil
  end
```

Booking belongs_to variant and a variant_id is saved in the booking. date_from is also a field in the Booking model.

When I try to run the validation I get NoMethodError: undefined method `tour' for nil:NilClass.

How can I get access to the variant before create?

**EDIT:**

Still having trouble with this, so let's try it in console.

```
b = Booking.new
b.valid?
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `tour' for nil:NilClass
```

variant.tour.price_details.each do |pd| is the line that fails.
Same happens if I do

```
b = Booking.new(:variant_id => params[:variant_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get variant's methods and properties from booking make sure you have assigned the variant_id to your new booking instance, like that: `booking = Booking.new(:variant_id => params[:variant_id])`. You then can call save method on booking. I assume that `variant_id` is available in a params hash of your controller methods.

Comment: I'm trying to get the booking.variant the user selected. A Booking belongs_to a variant. The User can select a variant from the form and it will be saved in the Booking table as variant_id.

Comment: I've edited my original question in regards to the belongs_to.

Comment: Has the variant_id been assigned? Try checking the before_save method in console to see if `Booking.new(...).variant` actually is not nil.

Comment: Updated my question after trying your suggestion.

Comment: Would you also show console output of `b = Booking.new(:variant_id => Variant.first.id); print b.variant`? params[:variant_id] might not be defined in the console and I still assume that `b.variant_id` is not defined just before the call of before_save helper. If it is still nil I would look closely into the definition of associations in your models.

Comment: The output from that is nil, would it work to do a before_save and find the variant object that way?

Comment: before_save helper would give you the same error, if `b.variant` is nil. There is something wrong with the associated models. Check your model definitions, db migrations, check the console output for just `Booking` (to make sure it has variant_id attribute), make sure the variant_id attribute is not protected, try console `Variant.first.bookings` to see the basic mechanism in action, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7250/discussion-between-alexei-danchenkov-and-amunds)

Answer (score 0):

Its just because associated record is not found hence returning NIL.
`b = Booking.new(:variant_id => params[:variant_id])`
here variant_id is not located in `variants` table